# How to use scope "test" and junit correctly with maven and eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit

I am trying to understand what I am doing wrong with junit-tests in Maven with eclipse. Mainly I have been just following this "getting started guide" for Maven:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/maven/

But for me it is not completely working like that when it comes to junit.

To follow the exact folder-structure from the example I have named my packages under src in eclipse:
main.java.hello
test.java.hello

My test class GreeterTest.java is in the package test.java.hello and has this content:

```
package test.java.hello;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.containsString;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;

import main.java.hello.Greeter;

public class GreeterTest {

    private Greeter greeter = new Greeter();

    @Test
    public void greeterSaysHello() {
        assertThat(greeter.sayHello(), containsString("Hello"));
    }

}
```

In my pom.xml you find the dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Unfortunately eclipse sais "the import org.junit cannot be resolved." 
If change the scope of the dependency from test to compile I do not get this error message, but that would be not the way how the scope is intended to be used, is it?

What do I need to change that also eclipse understands, that this class is a test-class and therefore all dependencies are actually available?

Best,Nils

Comment: The fact your class has package `test.java.Hello` suggests that maybe your project layout is incorrect. Please show the tree structure of your project, specifically the location of your tests.

Comment: Make sure the test code is not in the folder `src/main/java` but in the folder `src/test/java` (see [this short video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U-ZTkhek5TU&t=218s)). Maybe you also have to right-click the project and choose _Maven > Update Projects..._. If this does not help, please add a screenshot of the _Package Explorer_ view that shows the location of the files.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue appears to be related to where Eclipse thinks your source tree starts.  You have put your code in `src/main/java/hello` and `src/main/test/hello` but Eclipse thinks the source tree starts at `src`.  So it thinks the other folders are packages and has given your classes package names like `main.java.hello.Greeter`.

The quickest way to fix this is to run on the command line:

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

which uses maven to fix your eclipse projects.  It will automatically set the source root to be the correct values.  When it completes, right click on the project and select `Refresh` to see the updated project.

To fix this manually, you can right click on the project and choose `Build Path > Configure Build Path` and, in the `Source` tab on the right, ensure that the entire `src/main/java` (right up to `java`!) is included as the source folder. Do this by clicking `Add Folder` and selecting `java` in the tree under `src - main`. Do the same for `src/main/test`.  Usually maven projects include `src/main/resources` as a source folder too.